# playwright find child element(s) within locator

Tags: automation, playwright

I'm trying to write a function to find child(ren) element(s) within a locator something like:

```
async findElements(locator: Locator){
  return locator.querySelector(some/xpath/or/css);
}
```

However, I'm seeing the querySelector is not available in Locator. What is the equivalent of querySelector?

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] with sample HTML so the context is clear.

Comment: See this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/78085021

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out,

```
locator.locator(some/xpath/)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just started working with **playwright**.  So this may not be the exact answer that are looking for.

I am studying playwright with an existing repository.

[https://github.com/twerske/ng-tube/blob/main/src/app/video-grid/video-grid.component.html]

In this scenario I just want to know that I am getting a list of cards back.

```
<div class="videos-grid">
  <mat-card *ngFor="let video of videos" class="video-card">
```

I don't need a reference to a parent for this situation.  I am able to simply reference the child by class **videos-grid**.   This all exists inside of a angular's For loop.  I know Svelte and other frameworks iterate through lists in different ways.

```html
test.only('ngTube has header and cardList', async ({browser}) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    await page.goto("http://localhost:4200/")
    const title = await page.locator('.header-title').textContent();
    const videoList = (await page.locator('.video-card').allTextContents()).length;
    // await page.pause();
    expect(title).toStrictEqual('ngTube');
    expect(videoList).toBeGreaterThan(0)
})
```

Because I want all text contents I can get everything with the classname **'.video-card'**.

I guess what I am getting at is as long as you can access an identifier you should be able to directly access it.  As I run through the documentation more and scenarios I will update/add to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do this is to add a second testId in the nested elements then

```
parentLocator.getByTestId('nested-test-id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [**Filter by child/descendant**](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#filter-by-childdescendant):

Simple Example:
[image]

```
await page
    .getByRole('listitem')
    .filter({ has: page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Product 2' }) })
    .getByRole('button', { name: 'Add to cart' })
    .click();
```